# How can I override a constructor of an inherited object?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This the script, i try to "override" the constructor of the inherit object `carree_t` of `rectangle_t` with a step of validation.

```
CREATE TYPE point_t AS OBJECT(
    --Attributs
    corX INT,
    corY INT
) INSTANTIABLE FINAL ;
/

CREATE TYPE ligne_t AS OBJECT(
    --Attributs
point_1 point_t,
point_2 point_t,
INSTANTIABLE FINAL MEMBER FUNCTION longueur RETURN BINARY_FLOAT
) INSTANTIABLE FINAL ;
/

CREATE TYPE figure_geometrique_t AS OBJECT(
    --Attributs
    num_fig int,
    --Methodes
    NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL MEMBER FUNCTION perimetre RETURN BINARY_FLOAT,
    NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL MEMBER FUNCTION surface RETURN BINARY_FLOAT
    ) NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL ;
/

CREATE TYPE rectangle_t UNDER figure_geometrique_t (
    --Attributs
    ligne_1 ligne_t,
    ligne_2 ligne_t,
    ligne_3 ligne_t,
    ligne_4 ligne_t,    

    --Méthodes
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION rectangle_t (point_1 IN point_t, point_3 IN point_t) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    OVERRIDING INSTANTIABLE FINAL MEMBER FUNCTION perimetre RETURN BINARY_FLOAT,
    OVERRIDING INSTANTIABLE FINAL MEMBER FUNCTION surface RETURN BINARY_FLOAT
    ) INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL
/

CREATE TYPE carree_t UNDER rectangle_t (
       CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION carree_t (point_1 IN point_t, point_3 IN point_t) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,       
    ) INSTANTIABLE FINAL
/

CREATE TYPE BODY rectangle_t AS 
      CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION rectangle_t (point_1 IN point_t, point_3 IN point_t) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS

      BEGIN
      SELF.ligne_1 := new ligne_t(point_1,point_t(point_1.corX, point_3.corY));
      SELF.ligne_2 := new ligne_t(point_t(point_1.corX, point_3.corY),point_3);
      SELF.ligne_3 := new ligne_t(point_3,point_t(point_3.corX, point_1.corY));
      SELF.ligne_4 := new ligne_t(point_t(point_3.corX, point_1.corY),point_1);
      RETURN;
      END;

      OVERRIDING INSTANTIABLE FINAL MEMBER FUNCTION perimetre RETURN BINARY_FLOAT   IS resultat BINARY_FLOAT;

      BEGIN
      resultat := (SELF.ligne_1.longueur * 2) + (SELF.ligne_2.longueur * 2);
      RETURN resultat;
      END;

      OVERRIDING INSTANTIABLE FINAL MEMBER FUNCTION surface RETURN BINARY_FLOAT
      IS resultat BINARY_FLOAT;

      BEGIN
      resultat := (SELF.ligne_1.longueur * SELF.ligne_2.longueur);
      RETURN resultat;
      END; 
END;
/

CREATE TYPE BODY carree_t AS 
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION carree_t (point_1 IN point_t, point_3 IN point_t) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS

      BEGIN
      SELF.ligne_1 := new ligne_t(point_1,point_t(point_1.corX, point_3.corY));
      SELF.ligne_2 := new ligne_t(point_t(point_1.corX, point_3.corY),point_3);
      SELF.ligne_3 := new ligne_t(point_3,point_t(point_3.corX, point_1.corY));
      SELF.ligne_4 := new ligne_t(point_t(point_3.corX, point_1.corY),point_1);
      IF NOT SELF.ligne_1.longueur = SELF.ligne_2.longueur THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20104, 'Carree Bad Format');
      END IF;    
      RETURN;
      END;
END;
/
```

Output say :
"Warning: Type created with compilation errors." on Type Carree.

and "show errors;" => "No errors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `show errors` immediately after the `CREATE TYPE carree_t` statement you will see:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
3/5      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

         not pragma <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> final instantiable
         current delete exists order overriding prior static member
         constructor map
```

If you wait until after you've successfully compiled some other type then `show errors` won't show you anything, as it looks for the most recent object. If that still doesn't show you anything, or you just want to look later, [you can query the `user_errors`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2c9f8/1) or `all_errors` views, which will show errors for all invalid objects.

In this case you just have a trailing comma after the constructor:

```
... RETURN SELF AS RESULT,       
    ) INSTANTIABLE FINAL
```

With that removed everything [compiles with no errors](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9bb36/1):

```
CREATE TYPE carree_t UNDER rectangle_t (
       CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION carree_t (point_1 IN point_t, point_3 IN point_t)
           RETURN SELF AS RESULT      
    ) INSTANTIABLE FINAL
/
```